# Function keys with Apple wired keyboard not as expected

Tags: mac, keyboard

I am using a Retina iMac 5K running Mac OS X El Capitan connected with a Apple A1843 wired (USB) keyboard with F1 thru F19 and numpad.

**I expect** (as per icons on key-tops):

`F1` dim brightness
`F2` brighten
`F3` mission control
`F4` multiple windows
...etc...
`F10` mute
`F11` sound quieter
`F12` sound louder,
and `F13` - `F19` not assigned

**What I get**:

all `F` keys do nothing, except `F14` (old `F1`, dims screen), and `F15` (old `F2`, brighten), regardless of state of `fn` modifier key.

**A complication**:

I cannot get the function keys at top of the keyboard to work as advertised, even with the modifier keys (<kbd>fn</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>, command). I tried to check the box for `Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys` under `System Preferences → Keyboard` but the option is missing.

[image: screenshot of Mac dialog]

**A test of key scans**:

I ran the xev program in XQuartz (X11) environment and verified that the system is responding to keypresses on the function keys (see comments).

Q: How do I reset the function keys to do what they advertise?

Comment: What steps have you tried so far to fix this? Also, is this the keyboard that came with your iMac?

Comment: I have tried different kbd combinations and rebooting. The keyboard is an Apple kbd but it did not come with the iMac (which uses a Bluetooth one).

Comment: Have you attempted to use a different wired or wireless keyboard?

Comment: Those keys may not be functioning.  See [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317548/how-do-i-get-the-calculator-button-on-a-microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-working/317556#317556) for a way to determine if macOS is seeing the key presses.

Comment: @Allan I installed XQuartz and ran the xev command as specified. The system sees F1 thru F13 but has no symbol for F14 thru F19.

Comment: @Jake3231 no other kbds available

Comment: model A1843 USB kbd with numpad

Comment: Yes I am seeing the keypresses - reread the comment. SE wants us to stop this extended comment.

Comment: Do you get a scan code(s) when you press F14 - F19?  Not *symbols*, scan codes.

Comment: yes I get scan codes for F13, and F16-19. F14 and F15 adjust the screen brightness like F1 and F2 were supposed to do. This seems to be getting off track. I just want my functions back.

Comment: It's off track because details are missing.  This is the first we're hearing about F14/15 now adjust brightness.  From your question and everything up to that point was that, as you stated *"I cannot get the function keys at top of the keyboard to work,"*.  Please [edit your question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/320982/edit) and describe **specifically** the issue you're having.