# Make standard keyboard and function keys to work

Tags: keyboard

I have this keyboard https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012 and am running Sierra on my Mac.

How can I make all the function keys (F1, F2, F3 ....) work?
They are not responding.

This is my config: 
[image]

**Update, looks like the drivers are installed**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you notice on that page the downloads tab where they have drivers for this keyboard only through macOS 10.7. You may need to get a keyboard with drivers compatible with your current OS

Comment: What @SteveChambers said about compatibility is key.  Just because the driver is  loaded doesn't magically make it compatible.

Comment: The bottom line here is macOS ***must*** see the keyboard scan codes or they won't work.  See this related post on how to diagnose:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317548/how-do-i-get-the-calculator-button-on-a-microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-working/317556#317556