# How can I fix my USB volume control from changing the volume two steps at a time?

Tags: keyboard, audio, usb, script, sound-volume

I have this [USB volume control](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T4KD588), but when I adjust the volume, it adjusts it two steps at a time.

When I connect it, it registers as a USB keyboard.

My guess is that it is sending the "keypress" for the volume change twice.

1. Is there a way to confirm that it is sending two keypresses?
2. (If step 1. confirms it) Is there a way to write a script to detect this and ignore the second keypress?

Thanks!

Comment: To see if it's sending key presses, use the `xev` utility.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317556/119271 and as far as writing a "script", it's not that simple - you'd need a listener application (applescript is not the right tool for this job) to continually watch for and intercept it, and that's a project/question for the folks over at [so]

Comment: Interesting - it doesn't show anything! My bluetooth keyboard and the laptop keyboard both show events for normal keypresses, but when I change the volume (on the bluetooth keyboard, laptop touch bar or USB volume control) nothing comes up in xev (but the volume still changes). Maybe it registers as a touchbar event? Is there an equivalent of xev for touchbar events?

Comment: then it's not a key press.  volume up/down are "hooks" in the OS; certain keys just happen to be mapped to those hooks.  I suspect (pretty sure actually) that USB controller is calling them directly and not sending keypresses.

Comment: Well, when I connect the USB volume control, it says a keyboard is connected, and when I press the volume button on my bluetooth keyboard, the same thing happens, so I guess it might be a "key press" in the same way that changing the volume from my keyboard is a "key press". I would guess that the USB volume control is a keypress in that respect, but that the OS maps the keypress from either device to the volume hook before `xev` gets to see what's happening.

Comment: When I connect my Logitech MX Master 3, it identifies it as a keyboard as well but that doesn't mean my scroll up/down or mouse moments translates to arrow keys.  What you described in relation to `xev` is not how it works.  `xev` is that listener app I was referring to - if a key is being pressed, `xev` is going to see it.  A key press simply cannot bypass it.

Comment: I meant "key press" in terms of the physical key that I press on my bluetooth keyboard to change the volume, which `xev` doesn't see. So if the OS doesn't map it to the volume hook before `xev` sees it, then I guess the keyboard itself must be translating the key press to the volume hook before sending it to the OS. Is there an equivalent command to `xev` that listens for the volume change hook being called?

Comment: There might be, but I currently am not aware of any.