# External USB Windows keyboard Ctrl key not working with MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

I'm using an USB Windows keyboard with my Macbook Pro 2017.

When I press the `Ctrl` key on it, nothing happens. I verified using https://www.keyboardtester.com/. It does not detect the key at all. I know that the hardware is fine, I verified using this keyboard with a Windows laptop.

My keyboard modifier keys settings look like this

[image]

Comment: I’ve never heard of that site, but if macOS isn’t seeing the key press, there’s not much you can do. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317556/119271) for a command to test your keyboard. Karabiner also has a utility to see if keys are being registered. Also, do you have this problem with Apple keyboards?

Comment: Thanks Allan, I will try out that command. Unfortunately, I don't own an Apple keyboard.