# How can I define Control and Command buttons on a Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Desktop keyboard?

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I want to use my new MacMini M1 with a [Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-sculpt-ergonomic-desktop/8xk02kz6k69w?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) keyboard.

It doesn't have a Command key so in order to use the hotkeys starting with Command I switched between Command and Control. But i also would like to use the hotkeys starting with Control, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317548/how-do-i-get-the-calculator-button-on-a-microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-working help, especially the answer recommending Karabiner Elements?

Comment: Without any modification the Windows key is recognised as Cmd, ctrl & alt act as printed.

Comment: Thanks all, just realized that it is actually true, the window key is indeed acts as a command button, as i said, i am new to mac :)